# Rest URL Path is Not Getting Mapped ( Spring Boot )

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Consider, following classes for my problem,

Boot Application java class :

```
package com.abb;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.abb.repositories"})
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

CrudRepository interface ( it just added here because i feel package might cause this issue ) :

```
package com.abb.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.abb.entities.XYZ;

public interface XYZRepository extends CrudRepository<XYZ, Long> { }
```

Controller Java Class For rest API:

```
package com.abb.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.abb.repositories.XYZRepository;

@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/abc") 
public class ABCController {

     @Autowired
     private XYZRepository xyzRepository;

     @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public @ResponseBody String test(@RequestBody int iValue) {
          return "done" + iValue; 
     }
}
```

Server Logs :

```
2017-10-25 22:22:25.579  INFO 4664 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-10-25 22:22:26.291  INFO 4664 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4521e6e2: startup date [Wed Oct 25 22:22:17 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-10-25 22:22:26.470  INFO 4664 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-10-25 22:22:26.485  INFO 4664 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-10-25 22:22:26.548  INFO 4664 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-10-25 22:22:26.548  INFO 4664 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-10-25 22:22:26.657  INFO 4664 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-10-25 22:22:27.250  INFO 4664 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-10-25 22:22:27.344  INFO 4664 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-10-25 22:22:27.470  INFO 4664 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-10-25 22:22:27.486  INFO 4664 --- [  restartedMain] com.yq.WhyqueueServerApplication         : Started WhyqueueServerApplication in 10.814 seconds (JVM running for 11.612)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are limiting spring boots scanner to only scan the repositories package. No other package will be scanned. This means it does not pick up your controllers, which are in "com.abb.controllers" package.

Remove the scanBasePackages attribute, replace the value, or add each individual package that you want scanned.

I recomend this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

Or this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.abb"})
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help:)